# Rails4 で lib ディレクトリの自作ライブラリを読み込めない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Rails3.2からRails4.0最新バージョンに上げたところ自作で作ったライブラリが読み込めなくなりました。
作成していたライブラリは以下のようなものです。

- lib/active_support/core_ext/object.rb

  ```
  require 'active_support/core_ext/object/hoge'
  ```
- lib/active_support/core_ext/object/hoge.rb

  ```
  class Float
    def hoge(poge=0)
      moge = 10.0 ** poge
    end
  end
  ```

Floatを拡張したhogeメソッドを呼び出すことが出来ません。Rails3.2では動いていました。
config/application.rbにconfig.autoload_pathsを追記してみても呼び出せませんでした。
app/models/concernsにおいても駄目でした。
読み込み方法を教えて頂きたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Railsのバージョンの違いが原因かどうかは定かではないですが、autoload先の定数（モジュール／クラス）に対する理解があやふやになっているかと思います。

まず、autoloadするlib以下のディレクトリ構造は、定義する定数の構造と一致していなければなりません。
以下のサイトが分かりやすいと思います。
http://easyramble.com/auto-load-rails-lib.html

その点を踏まえた上で、じゃあその構造通りに定義すれば上手くいくのかといえば、そうもいきません。`config.autoload_paths`にlibを追加しても、autoloadの探索先に追加されるだけであって、自動的にrequireしてくれるわけではありません。requireされるのは、（大雑把に言うと）初めてその定数にアクセスしたときです。

autoloadの挙動を理解したければ、以下のような手順で確認できます。

lib/extensions.rb

```
p '★★★★★★★'
module Extensions
end
```

`rails c`を実行して、コンソール上で`Extensions`と入力すると、

```
"★★★★★★★"
=> Extensions
```

と表示され、ここで初めてこのファイルが読み込まれているのが分かります。

ご質問内容は`Float`に対するモンキーパッチで、定義済みの定数に対するautoloadなので、結果的には明示的にrequireをしてやる必要があります。ただし、autoloadされる側でrequireを呼ぶのはバッドプラクティスなので、initializerを使用するのが定石です。

lib/extensions.rb

```
class Float
  def hoge(poge=0)
    moge = 10.0 ** poge
  end
end
```

config/initializers/require.rb

```
require 'extensions'
```

参考

- http://easyramble.com/auto-load-rails-lib.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098663/auto-loading-lib-files-in-rails-4
- http://railsguides.jp/constant_autoloading_and_reloading.html

Comment: initializersに追加することで読み込めるようになりました。Rails3でなぜ読み込めていたのか分かりませんが

Comment: ActiveSupport::Autoloadの挙動が変わったんだと思います。3.2で例のコードを実行すると、rails起動時に`"★★★★★★★"`が表示されますので。